# Make a Dynamic Drop Down Navigation system

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to create a Dropdown Menu on my site, Ive hit a brick wall and cannot think on how to do it.

Basically i need to check 2-3 variables in a database and out put the correct data.

I have at the moment it checking if its an External Link or Not, and if it contains a submenu, but i can't get it to output the correct information.

Basically i want it to check if its a External or Non-External link, and if it has a submenu, if it has a submenu, to display the menu options underneath it. So say i have menu 1, 2 ,3, 4 and 2,4 has a submenu, i need them to list the other links under them. i have put in my database toplink_id (to represent which link this item should be under) sc_order (which will control the order the sublinks display in) also dropdown (which tells me if the menu has a submenu or not.)

Here is the start of my code

```
$sql = "SELECT label, url, ext, dropdown FROM content_pages WHERE top_nav='1' AND active='1' ORDER by page_order ASC"; 
$query = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($dbc));

$menuDisplay .= '<div class="bg-2"><div class="container_12"><article class="grid_12"><nav><ul class="menu sf-js-enabled">';

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 

$url = $row["url"];
$nav_label = $row["label"];
$drop_down ='<ul><li><a href="../pages/' . $url . '">' . $nav_label . '</a></li></ul>'; 


if ($row["ext"] == 0 && $row["dropdown"] == 1){

$menuDisplay .= '<li><a href="../pages/' . $url . '">' . $nav_label . '</a>'  . $drop_down . '</li>';
}

elseif ($row["ext"] == 1 && $row["dropdown"] == 1){

$menuDisplay .= '<li><a href="../' . $url . '">' . $nav_label . '</a>'  . $drop_down . '</li>';
 }
 elseif ($row["ext"] == 0){

$menuDisplay .= '<li><a href="../pages/' . $url . '">' . $nav_label . '</a></li>';
}

elseif ($row["ext"] == 1)
{
    $menuDisplay .= '<li><a href="../' . $url . '">' . $nav_label . '</a></li>';
}



} 
$menuDisplay .= '</ul></nav></article></div></div></header>';   
mysqli_free_result($query);
```

Comment: you should be using `jquery` for that

Comment: Where specifically are you getting stuck? I don't see any attempt to pull the sub-items from each primary item.

Comment: Um everywhere to be perfectly honest. Ive lost which direction to go forward from here. I got a complete mind blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way I found to do this without using jQuery is use multidimensional Arrays.

```
    // Create a multidimensional array to conatin a list of items and parents
$menu = array(
    'items' => array(),
    'parents' => array(),
);
// Builds the array lists with data from the menu table


while ($items = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{

    // Creates entry into items array with current menu item id ie. $menu['items'][1]
    $menu['items'][$items['id']] = $items;
    // Creates entry into parents array. Parents array contains a list of all items with children
    $menu['parents'][$items['parent']][] = $items['id'];
}

// Menu builder function, parentId 0 is the root

function buildMenu($parent, $menu)
{

    $html = "\n";
   if  ( isset($menu['parents'][$parent]) )
   {

      $html .= "";

       foreach ($menu['parents'][$parent] as $itemId)

       {
    if(!isset($menu['parents'][$itemId]) && $menu['items'][$itemId]['ext'] == 0)
    {
         $html .= "<li>\n  <a href='../pages/".$menu['items'][$itemId]['link']."'>".$menu['items'][$itemId]['label']."</a>\n</li> \n";
    }
    else
                if(!isset($menu['parents'][$itemId]) && $menu['items'][$itemId]['ext'] == 1)
    {
         $html .= "<li>\n  <a href='../".$menu['items'][$itemId]['link']."'>".$menu['items'][$itemId]['label']."</a>\n</li> \n";
    }


if(isset($menu['parents'][$itemId]))
          {

             $html .= "<li>\n  <a href='../pages/".$menu['items'][$itemId]['link']."'>".$menu['items'][$itemId]['label']."<span class='arrow-down'></span></a> \n";
        $html .= "<ul style='border-radius: 0px 0px 6px 6px'> \n";
             $html .= buildMenu($itemId, $menu);
        $html .= "</ul> \n";
             $html .= "</li> \n";

          }   

    }
    $html .= "\n";
   }
   $html .= "";
return $html;

}
```